# "a clothing style to suit everyone", how do I make it less like an Ad?

Tags: logic

Consider this conversation

> question: Why do you think jeans are popular in your country?
>
> answer: they come in many different styles, so there is **a style to suit everyone**.

In clothing, there is no such thing as "a style to suit everyone", is that expression illogical? If yes, how do I fix it?

Is this sentence clear and natural?

> ... so **there is a style to suit you**.

which means some style suits her, another style suits him.

Does it sound like an Ad?

How about this one? Does it sound less like an Ad?

> Most people I know like wearing jeans even at work, because it can match many kinds of styles.

Is it sentence clear and natural?

Comment: Here, 'everyone' means 'each person'. It's certainly ambiguous, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an advertising claim. They say that jeans come in so many different styles, that there is one that suits, or is apt for, everyone.

There is no difference between "everyone" and "you", if the claim is widely publicized.

Of course, some people won't like jeans at all, so like most ads, it's not quite true.